# How to localize custom ValidationAttribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The following code is of a custom validation attribute I have written for my hobby project, what I would like to do is to customize the error message of this validation attribute. I have declared "ErrorMessageResourceType" and "ErrorMessageResourceName" but I don't know how to extract text from these two properties. Could someone please tell me how to customize the error message of this validation attribute or extract text from ErrorMessageResourceType?

```
public class PasswordChecker : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private string defaultErrorMessage = "{0} must be greater than {1} characters";
    private string propertyName;
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessageResourceName { get; set; }

    public Type ErrorMessageResourceType { get; set; }

    public int MinLength { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        propertyName = validationContext.MemberName;

        if (value == null || value.ToString().Length < MinLength)
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage == null ? string.Format(defaultErrorMessage, propertyName, MinLength) : ErrorMessage);

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage == null ? string.Format(defaultErrorMessage, propertyName, MinLength) : ErrorMessage;
        rule.ValidationType = "passwordchecker";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("minlength", MinLength);

        return new[] { rule };
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to define properties for `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` - the [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) class already has those properties

Comment: You set the values when you declare the attribute  - e.g.  `[PasswordChecker(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "password")]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have removed the mentioned properties however I am confused about how to return the validation message from the resources

Comment: Perhaps [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/07/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx/) will help you understand it.